# AWS Lambda Java compatiblity

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS has introduced [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), *an event driven computing service for dynamic applications*, which I hope allows me to realize the following:

It should take a link and then perform HTTP requests and process the incoming responses from this requests. For this procedure I need multiple programs, which are executed in a queue. So the Lambda function has to execute several Java/C++ programs  and some Python scripts from the Lambda function. If this is not possible, can I then convert this code/the executables into Node.js modules and use everything within the same procedure this way?

I'm wondering if this is possible with AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When AWS announced Lambda, they mentioned it will be extended to other programming languages in the future. Java and Python (or Jython) are likely candidates being considered.

As of today, Lambda functions support node.js and are executed on Amazon EC2 instances.

Anything packaged as a nodejs module and based on Linux binaries should be able to run on lambda.

Remember also that your lambda function execution time is 60 seconds at max. Your function will be interrupted if it runs above that limit.

---

**[UPDATE March 2016]**

Lambda now supports Java8 and Python 2.7 execution environments in addition of NodeJS.
Execution time has been extended to 300 sec max.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Comment: Will AWS Lambda be aviable for non business (private people and developers) in future ?

Comment: Lambda is available in preview mode for all AWS customers, private persons and business. 

You can create an AWS account at http://aws.amazon.com/ and benefit from the free tier today ! http://aws.amazon.com/free/

You can apply to participate to the preview program at http://aws.amazon.com/lambda/preview/

Comment: Is 60sec max just for the preview? Is that likely to increase? I feel like 60sec, given random internet timeouts/DNS errors that occur in the cloud, does not seem very long at all

Comment: Lambda preview is now open to all - no need to request access !  And yes, the 60 secs limit is setup during the preview, it is likely to be extended when Lambda will be Generally Available